# Hyperlink image in PowerShell

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

Is it possible to have an image in Sitecore PowerShell Extensions GUI that has an embedded hyperlink to open a web page? For instance, if I had an image of a car in a PowerShell GUI form and when a user clicks the image, it would open https://cars.com.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to sitecore cms.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to add a hyperlink to the dialog produced by `Read-Variable`.

**Example:** The following example produces a dialog with a hyperlink.

```
$props = @{
    "Parameters" = @(
        @{ Name = "info"; Title = "Fancy Link"; Value = "<a href='https://www.google.com' target='_blank'>CLICK ME</a>"; Editor = "info" }
    )
    "Title" = "Sample Download Wizard"
    "Icon" = "OfficeWhite/32x32/server_from_client.png"
    "ShowHints" = $true
    "OkButtonName" = "Next"
}
Read-Variable @props
```

[image: Example Dialog]

Comment: What version of powershell are you running?  When I try the Read-Variable, I get that it isn't a cmdlet or fuction....  I'm running powershell 7

Answer (score 0):

Adding more to @Michael answer, So if you want to add image then you can add the path of your media library item like below.

```
    $props = @{
    "Parameters" = @(
        @{ Name = "info"; Title = "Image With Link"; Value = "<a href='https://cars.com' target='_blank'><img src='/-/media/Default Website/sc_logo.jpg'></a>"; Editor = "info" }
    )
    "Title" = "Sample Download Wizard"
    "Icon" = "OfficeWhite/32x32/server_from_client.png"
    "ShowHints" = $true
    "OkButtonName" = "Next"
    }
    Read-Variable @props
```

It will look like the below.

[image]

Hope it help.

Comment: ok I feel a bit silly.  I think i'm posting in the wrong group.  I don't use Sitecore....This is just straight powershell.  Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: @Todd No worry, at least it will be helpful for someone else.